# NL2BR() PHP problem help please?

Tags: php, mysql, html, nl2br

So on my website you are able to send messages. I use the nl2br() function so if someone presses enter, their text will have linebreaks. I realized though, if the person typing the text doesn't press enter and is instead wrapped by the textarea, the text is still broken. How can I avoid this? (How can I avoid linebreaks if the user doesn't press enter)

Comment: If the textarea is wrapping there should be no line breaks inserted. Check your resulting data, something else is going on. Or maybe the problem isn't clear.

Comment: Do you have the `wrap="hard"` attribute set in your textarea for some reason?

Comment: Yes I do have wrap="hard." Why? Does this affect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

I had wrap="hard" so when I changed it to wrap="soft" the user had to press enter to add linebreaks. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CSS style `overflow: auto` on the textarea so that the textarea will render with a scrollbar if the text exceeds the width of the textarea.

```css
#textareaId {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm failing to see how is this a relevant solution?

Comment: @Jason I'm guessing that the OP means the text is being wrapped in the textarea, not when actually extracted from the textarea (which I assume to work correctly).

Answer (score 2):

Set up your textarea like this:

```
<textarea style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: auto;">
</textarea>
```

Browser will no longer display automatic wraps, and will add scrollbars when user types past the right edge.

Answer (score 1):

The linebreaks caused by wrapping in the textarea are only displayed in the browser and will not be submitted with the form. If you don't want them to be converted to `<br />`, that's fine, because they won't. (Not sure I understand your question.)